# How to restore a cluster backup in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dump, pg-restore

I am trying to restore a cluster backup in PostgreSQL. I used pg_dumpall and it generated a plain text file with SQL queries. However, when I try to restore it, I get this error:

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid
>   archive

I had also received the same error when I had tried to restore databases' backups (generated with pg_dump) but I solved that problem. In that case pg_restore did not recognize plain text with SQL queries, so I changed the command:

```
pg_dump db_name -Fc -U user -h host -p port > my_db_backup.dump
```

And wrote instead:

```
pg_dump db_name -Fp -U user -h host -p port > my_db_backup.dump
```

This way the generated file was not in plain text, so pg_restore worked well with that.

Now, I am trying the manage the same with pg_dumpall, but there is not a -F param for that one. My code (in Python3, but this command would be the same for any language) is:

```
pg_dumpall -U user -h host -p port > my_cluster_backup.dump
```

Any idea of how to manage this? Or at least how to restore a cluster backup in any way? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

If I use *psql* to restore:

```
psql -U user -h host -p port -f my_cluster_backup.dump postgres'
```

It seems to work, a lot of commands are shown in console, but each of them gives a "it already exists" error. I cannot understand because I have two clusters (ports 5432 and 5433) and I guess it is trying to restore in 5432, when I am sure that I am connected to 5433. Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 8):

See the example at  the end of [pg_dumpall doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html):

> To dump all databases:
>
> $ pg_dumpall > db.out
>
> To reload database(s) from this file, you can use:
>
> $ psql -f db.out postgres
>
> (It is not important to which database you connect here since the
>   script file created by pg_dumpall will contain the appropriate
>   commands to create and connect to the saved databases.)

`db.out` in this example is a SQL commands script, meant to be fed directly to the `psql` interpreter.

[pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) does not work with a plain SQL file as input. Its main/original purpose is to take as input a backup in a non-text format (e.g. `pg_dump -Fc`) and produce the corresponding SQL file as output, or to restore directly into the database using parallel paths (`-j`)

When the input is already a SQL script, there's really no point in using `pg_restore` rather than `psql`, so presumably that's why the authors didn't bother to support SQL scripts as input to `pg_restore`.

Comment: Thank you, now I am using psql, but there are some problems. I am going to edit my question to show what happens when I use psql.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you have pg_basebackup to backup an entire node.

Comment: thanks for the keyword to research :-) ... [Postgresql Homepage, Doku of pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-pgbasebackup.html)